# Execute select statement conditionally

Tags: postgresql, subquery, union, where-clause, plpgsql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and I need to create a query that performs a select depending on the logic of an if

Basically I've tried:

```
DO $$  
BEGIN 
IF exists ( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE A = B ) THEN
  SELECT *
  FROM A
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM B
END IF
END $$
```

And that returns me an error:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM
> instead.
>
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 15 at SQL statement

Then I switched "SELECT" for "PERFORM", but that don't actually execute the SELECT statement for me.

I read that I need to call a void function to perform a "dynamic" query, but I couldn't make that work either. I'm new to writing queries on PostgreSQL. Is there any better way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statements do not take parameters nor return anything. See:

- [Returning values for Stored Procedures in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271247/3684)

You may want a function instead. Create once:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS SETOF A  --  or B, all the same
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN 
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM ...) THEN  -- some meaningful test
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT *
      FROM A;
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT *
      FROM B;
   END IF;
END
$func$
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo();
```

**But** the function has *one* declared return type. So both tables `A` and `B` must share the same columns (at least columns with compatible data types in the same order; names are no problem).
The same restriction applies to a plain SQL statement. SQL is strictly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous code blocks just can't return anything - you would need a function instead.

But I think you don't need pl/pgsql to do what you want. Assuming that `a` and `b` have the same count of columns and datatypes, you can use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select a.* from a where exists (select 1 from mytable where ...)
union all
select b.* from b where not exists (select 1 from mytable where ...)
```